# How to access the mirror api from within a push queue?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I'd like to access the mirror service api from inside push queue worker. What's the idiomatic way of doing this? Ideally, I'd like something as easy as the `auth_required` decorator in the quickstart repo. Of course I know it's not going to be so easy since I have to store a user's credentials somehow and associate them with a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'm doing it (with appengine in python) is to pass the user ID in addition to whatever information is necessary to the push queue worker, and then retrieve user credentials for the user ID inside of the worker.

Here's my implementation of a worker: https://github.com/Scarygami/mirror-api/blob/master/examples/colours-of-the-world/tasks.py

And here where I push the tasks to the queue, reacting to Mirror API notifications: https://github.com/Scarygami/mirror-api/blob/master/examples/colours-of-the-world/notify.py

I also did a short write-up about using push queues for Glassware a while ago: https://gist.github.com/Scarygami/5539534